# binding argument to ansi c callback

Tags: c++, tr1

I have function, lets say foo, in lib which accepts callback:

```
typedef void (*CallbackType)(unsigned int); 
void foo(const tchar* path, CallBackType); // library function

static void boo(unsigned int percent)
{
static ProgressBarClass progressBar;
 progressBar.setProgressValue(percent);
}
```

but I can't have object progressBar to be static, so I thought I will bind reference to it:

```
static void boo(unsigned int percent, ProgressBarClass& progressBar)
{
    progressBar.setProgressValue(percent);
}

void something() {
    ProgressBarClass progressBar;
    tr1::function<static void(unsigned int)> f = tr1::bind(boo, tr1::placeholders::_1, tr1::ref(progressBar));
    foo(someWCHARPath, f);
}
```

but of course I can't convert tr1::function to ansi c callback, so the question is is there anything nice and clean what can I do? Can I bind progressBar is some way to ansi c callback?

Comment: Your reference "solution" would be broken since `progressBar`'s lifetime ends when `something` returns.

Comment: foo fills progress bar using callback, so it would not be broken.

Comment: I was thinking that `foo` was asynchronous. Brain malfunction, sorry.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "ansi c callback"? A plain function which can get called through a function pointer?

Comment: @Lundin, typedef void (*CallbackType)(unsigned int) means ansi c callback for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to resort to a global function with exactly that signature. Since you're given the function pointer type `typedef void (*CallbackType)(unsigned int)`, your callback needs to return `void` and take one `unsigned int` parameter:

```
void function(unsigned int);
CallbackType funcPtr = &function;
```

If the callback doesn't provide a "user data" argument (usually a `void*`) to pass additional data, you either have to fit them somehow to the existing arguments (maybe it's possible to use some bits of the integer), or use global variables, which I wouldn't recommend unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: can you give me some example how you imagine that "resort to a global function"?

Comment: @user1326505 I edited my answer correspondingly. Basically, in C you don't have an option to use any of the nice features (e.g. bind, lambda) that C++11 functionals provide.

Comment: well boo function is that global one, but it has to get same reference to ProgressBarClass object class somehow, so I can use boo function for example 100 times. maybe there is just no good solution...

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid there is no clean solution in that case (only global variables, which allow only a single callback to be executed simultaneously and introduce many other problems). That's why well-thought C callback APIs provide additional `void*` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If any object of type `ProgressBarClass` is OK, just remove the `static` keyword.

If you need some specific object of type `ProgressBarClass`, then no, there's no way to pass one around through the C callback you have. You must have *some kind* of  static variable which allows you to get the object. It doesn't have to be a `ProgressBarClass`. Perhaps you should have a singleton that represent your application, with methods that return its various GUI elements.

Comment: not any object is good, because it is progress bar class, so I need to "remember" that I already filled progress e.g. by 50%.